# How do you trace back the source of an audio stream on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio

iPhone SE, latest iOS.

There's an audio stream - a spoken word podcast I think, playing on my device.  I have no idea where it came from.  I didn't ask it to play any audio.

If I turn the side power button off, the screen goes blank. If I push it again, it comes up on the lock screen, and there's the usual audio control panel with play, fast forward, rewind and Airplay buttons. This control will pause the audio.    So clearly, the audio is interacting with iOS in the normal way.

But how do I find out where it came from in the first place?  Which app is originating it?  If it's Safari, which tab is originating it?   I tried tapping on the top area of the audio icon, but it just asked for my lock code and took me to the home screen.

I had a number of Safari windows open, one of which was a discussion forum. Could a user-contributed embed in a discussion forum post cause audio to autoplay?  The item is "Abigail from TikTok" and I don't have TikTok, no app, no account, no relation whatsoever, and none of my browser windows were open to TikTok anything.

It's definitely not iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

### Where does the sound come from?

Click on the name of the audio playing ("Make It Rain - Johan Borjesson [House Music]" in the below example). It should lead you the where the sound is coming from.

[image]

[image] [image]

### Stop it playing

Play another sound on purpose. It should overrun the currently playing sound. Then, wait some time (about 10s) to be sure it performs the desired action) and stop playing the sound (quit the app or website it comes from).